# Trying to cross reference one CSV to another

Tags: python, csv

So I have two CSV files, one with a list of names that might be a match or might not match the list of names in another file. But if it does find a match I want it to go back to the original csv1 and a different column value from csv2 from the same row as the match to the second row in csv1.

```
with open('/Users/{}/Desktop/{}.csv'.format(os.getlogin(), mainFile), mode='r') as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
for i in csv_reader:
    with open('/Users/{}/Desktop/{}.csv'.format(os.getlogin(), projects), mode='r') as new_csv:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(new_csv)
        for x in csv_reader:
            if i['Owner'] == x['Project Owner']:
                with open('/Users/{}/Desktop/{}.csv'.format(os.getlogin(), mainFile), mode='r') as csv_writing:
                    writer = csv.writer(csv_writing)
                    writer.writerow([x['Project Owner'], x['Project Name']])
```

this is what I have so far but I'm worried that it won't know what to do with the rows in csv1 that don't match and since I can loop a writer the best option would be to delete the row from csv1 that doesn't match right? So how would I delete that said row? Or a better solution if you have one.

Comment: You do NOT want to read the second file all over again for every line in the first file.  Instead, read the whole second file into a dictionary, then read the first file and look up the names in the dictionary you created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a `Table` helper in **convtools** library ([github](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools)). The helper simplifies basic operations for stream processing table-like data.

```py
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table
from convtools import conversion as c

Table.from_csv("tmp/main.csv", header=True).join(
    Table.from_csv("tmp/projects.csv", header=True),
    on=c.LEFT.col("Owner") == c.RIGHT.col("Project Owner"),
    how="inner",
).take("Project Owner", "Project Name").into_csv("tmp/results.csv")
```

Comment: that explains it, thank you